# Mean Value theorem, continuity...

Tags: functions, continuity, rational-numbers

suppose that $f$ is continuous on [a,b], and the range of $f$ consists of the whole Rational numbers,

prove that $f$ is a constant function

Help, Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $f$ takes two different rational values $a$ and $b$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem it takes all values in between.

**Hint 2** There exists irrational numbers between $a$ and $b$. For example $a+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(b-a)$.